# Visually Comparable Plot

Tags: matlab, plot

So I have to plot certain data (90 sets total) and a single set looks like this.

[image: PLOT]

However when I `hold on` and plot 90 sets superimposed, it looks just like a patch of multiple colours.

Now what would be the most optimal way to represent the plots that can let us compare them and study the difference. For example (**and this is just my thought and I am open to opnions**) how can I compare these 90 plots in a Matrix fashion viz.

[image: Sample Requirement]

Is there even better ways to represent such collection of plots instead of just superimposing them?

**EDIT:** To clear things up, I have **90 graphs that look similar to the first graph** and I have to compare them in say, a single page. What would be the best way to do it? Also is `subplot` the best idea for 90 graphs?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what sort of comparison you are looking for but you can (like you mentioned) create a 2D matrix of size 90 x 7000 and just plot the image with a colormap that suits your requirements.

Comment: edited answer for clarity

Comment: subplot probably is not the best idea. I would suggest plotting an image. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need subplot(), which allows you to plot multiple figures in one window.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: Is `subplot` the best idea for 90 graphs?

Comment: No, my better way would be for anything more than 16 images (personal rule of thumb) I would write all graphs as individual pngs and save them into a folder. then run this code https://gist.github.com/Krewn/6e9acdadddb4bf2a56c0 at that folder to create a brows-able html page. This way you can more easily scroll, organize the plots into sub folders (this will group them on the results page) and use the browser zoom to see more or less at once.

Comment: That code provided above associates things to a git.io page, you would modify it a little to suit our needs, but the point is the same, data scientists should aim for brow-sable results because it allows non computer scientists to pull up the results without running any code.

Comment: anything for a pdf document?

Comment: yeah, you can render a webpage and then use the browsers builtin print to generate pdfs.